# Separation of a delayed mixtures of signals

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis

I have three emitters in three different positions that emite three signals $S_1(t), S_2(t), S_3(t)$ with
$$S_1(t)=S_2(t)=S_3(t)$$
Two receivers recive $R_1(t), R_2(t)$ with
\begin{align}
R_1(t)&=r_1(t-D_1)+r_2(t-D_2)+r_3(t-D_3)\\
R_2(t)&=r_1(t-D_1)+r_2(t-D_2)+r_3(t-D_3)\\
r(t)&=\operatorname{conv}\big(S(t),\rm{Imp_r}\big)
\end{align}
Where $\rm Imp_r$ is a realization of the channel impulse response.

My goal is to separate $R(t)$ and get $r_1(t-D_1), r_2(t-D_2), r_3(t-D_3)$ with the exacte delays. ICA and SCA methods works only on instatinous mixtures, in this case we have a delayed mixtures. is there any other methods to solve this problem ?

[image]  [image]

Comment: My first reaction is there are two many unknowns given what you wrote: transmitting $S1(t)=S2(t)=S3(t)$ from three different locations over a dispersive channel $h[n]$  is identical to transmitting from one location with a new channel that has the two additional multipath elements. However $h[n]$ will also be different for both receivers wouldn't it? And it would be different for each individual tx-rx path as well I would guess. I'd be interested in seeing your data and the list of assumptions that can be made.Do your transmit signals have good spectral occupancy for doing channel estimation?

Comment: Your model is both having delayed signals and non LPF channel? I think it will be too much for anything practical.

Comment: To explain more, i'm using UWB IEEE 802.15.4a channel model and the impulse response of the channel is different for each tx-rx because of the different positions of the  three emitters.